# How to customize the plus/minus jQuery UI accordion images

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#custom-icons

I want to add those up down arrow icons in my Accordian below. How should I modify my code ? Need help badly. Thnx

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" FadeTransitions="true"  Visible="true" AutoSize="None"SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false"  TransitionDuration="250" 
HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader toggler" 
     HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader toggler-expanded" ContentCssClass="accordionContent">
                <HeaderTemplate>

                    <b style="color: Black">

                        <%#Eval("Ques")%>
                    </b>
                <ContentTemplate>
                <p> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuesAns")%></p>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:Accordion>
```

Comment: You should post the HTML that is generated by your .NET code.  It would make troubleshooting this much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change :

```
.toggler {         
     background:url("/images/icons/plus.png") no-repeat left center transparent;    
}         

.toggler-expanded {         
     background-image:url("/images/icons/minus.png");
}
```

to:

```
.toggler {         
     background:url("path/to/yourimage.png") no-repeat left center transparent;    
}         

.toggler-expanded {         
     background-image:url("path/to/yourimage.png");
}
```

But you should take a look at [jQuery theming](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).